# react-native-popup-menu MenuProvider typescript IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to achieve drop down options in Flatlist,
I have used React native popup Menu and in App.tsx I have declared the entry point as MenuProvider.
I am getting this error.

Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<MenuProviderProps, any, any>> & Readonly<...>
react-native-popup-menu MenuProvider typescript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any resolution? I have same issue using it with typescript

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to incorrectly resolved dependencies.
If you are using react 17 try adding the following lines to your package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
 "@types/react": "17.0.2",
 "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
}
```

This will force dependency versions marked as "*" to resolve to the specified versions in your json and should fix the issue, or at least it worked for me.
If you don't specify the "resolutions" property, dependencies marked as "*" will automatically resolve to react 18, causing the error.

Please also note that this question should be tagged as "react-native-popup-menu" too, to allow the community to track the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by using patch-package. I had modified node_modules/react-native-popup-menu/src/index.d.ts to have children prop type defined for each element that i have used.

Refer this [github](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/issues/248#issue-1310529637) issue i created for patch file